# jquery load time and css styling inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

like you see in the code below, the jquery loads a page  but it seems that all the .css styling inside the jquery waits until the jquery is loaded which can take some fraction of a second if the file is big. So if I have .css("display","none") it will not work for that time causing a flickering before the styling kicks in. I have this problem only with Mozilla. **The code below its only an example and it works well because is small**. Some ideas how to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".rectangle").click(function() {
  $("body").load("debugging2.html", function() {    
            $(".rectangle").css("display","none")
        $(".rectangle").fadeIn(1000);          
   }) ;        
   });
})
```

```css
.rectangle{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color:#000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>  
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Put styles in head, and jquery before closing body tag.

Comment: @dfsq Please re-post your comment as an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rectangle").click(function() {
        $("head").append("<style>.rectangle{display:none;}</style>");
        $("body").load("debugging2.html", function() {      
           $("rectangle").fadeIn(1000);                                     
        });                             
    });
})
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that the class rectangle will not be there before the page loads (you want to change the css of the page loaded not of the current page)

Comment: see modified answer, perhaps that will work for you.

Comment: the same default css kicks in before, the solution was simple: ""Put styles in head, and jquery before closing body tag. ""

Answer (score 0):

Since script tags are loaded synchronously (by default) they indeed block page rendering. It can result in blank unstyled page if HTML is not processed and styles are not loaded by that moment. Hence the common very simple solution is to move heavy script tags to the very end of the `</body>` and put necessary CSS style in the `<head>`.

As the result of above, CSS gets downloaded first, after HTML is loaded quickly, rendered and styled and only after that slow scripts get downloaded.

In code it will look something like this:

```
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="text/css" type="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div>  
    <div class="rectangle"></div>
  </div> 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- some other scripts -->
</body>
```

As the bonus, you don't need to bind to document ready event anymore (`$(document).ready(function() {});`), since HTML is all loaded by default, when scripts are executed.

Comment: I had already  my.js file just before the end of the body, do you mean I move there the minimize jquery cdn from google as well?